# Python Urllib is not found in sublime text 3

Tags: python, urllib

I'm new to python and got stuck in where package urllib in not working in sublime text 3, however its working in IDLE and command prompt. I've already built separate sublime-build but still no luck. Anybody please help me here.

> Error:
>
> from urllib.request import urlopen
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is
>   not a package

Comment: How are you trying to run the program you've written in Sublime?

Comment: Sublime thinks you're using Python 2, but you are actually using Python 3.

Comment: @kevin thanks for the reply, I have only installed python 3 in my system and please let me know how to use Python 3 as per your comment in sublime text 3.

Comment: @srireddy: I have no idea.  I don't use Sublime.  But that error message indicates Python 2.

Comment: @kevin Thanks Kevin for your effort. When I find the solution I will add here. cheers.